# Update value in array of string on array of objects mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, updates

I'm trying to update a value of a array of strings in mongodb, which is inside of another array of objects

here is an example of the model

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a8cd02f87d4839d279f6559"), 
    "category" : "0",
    "email" : "doctor@doctor.com",
    "password" : "doctor",
    "name" : "doctor",
    "directorys" : [ { 
                       "path" : "doctor@doctor.com/own/", 
                       "files" : [ "" ] 
                     }, 
                     {
                       "path" : "doctor@doctor.com/modified/",
                       "files" : [ "" ] 
                     },
                     { 
                      "path" : "doctor@doctor.com/own/pacient1", 
                      "files" : [ "", "README.txt" ] 
                     } 
                   ] }
}
```

**So im trying to update the name "README.txt" to "README2.txt" but i'm struggling with mongo**

i tried this

```
db.users.update({"email":"doctor@doctor.com","directorys.files":"README.txt"},{"$set":{"directorys.files.$":"README2.txt"}})
```

but throws the following error

```
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 16837,
        "errmsg" : "cannot use the part (directorys of directorys.files.2) to traverse the element ({directorys: [ { path: \"doctor@doctor.com/own/\", files: [ \"\" ] }, { path: \"doctor@doctor.com/modified/\", files: [ \"\" ] }, { path: \"doctor@doctor.com/own/pacient1\", files: [ \"\", \"README.txt\" ] } ]})"
    }
})
```

what i am missing? i dont know what to do

Comment: What is your mongodb version ?

Comment: ups, important detail, its 3.2.19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since directorys is an array, I think you need an array operator there as well. Try this query:

```
db.users.update(
    {"email":"doctor@doctor.com","directorys.files":"README.txt"},
    {"$set":{"directorys.$[selectedFiles].files.$":"README2.txt"}},
    {arrayFilters: [{"selectedFiles.files": "README.txt"}]}
)
```

You can see more about arrayFilters here:
[https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up.*S*[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E])

ArrayFilters allows you to take an array, select only those elements that match a certain criteria, and then apply $set (or any other update / upsert operator) to just those elements.

One thing though is that this will only update the first element of your files array that has README.txt. If README.txt is present more than once, you won't update all of them. If you want to update all elements in the array that are README.txt, you need a second arrayFilter, like this:

```
db.users.update(
    {"email":"doctor@doctor.com","directorys.files":"README.txt"},
    {"$set":{"directorys.$[selectedDirs].files.$[selectedFiles]":"README2.txt"}},
    {arrayFilters: [{"selectedDirs.files": "README.txt"}, {"selectedFiles": "README.txt"}]}
)
```

That should select all directorys elements with a files array that has at least one README.txt, then select all elements within that files array that equals README.txt, and then set those elements to README2.txt.

Comment: Hey thanks, i did not know that concept.
I try to copy-paste the first code that you wrote, only update one value is what i need, but that adds the value of "README2.txt" to the array.
I modify it a little bit and works like a charm
db.users.update(
    {"email":"doctor@doctor.com","directorys.files":"README.txt"},
    {"$set":{"directorys.$[].files.$[selectedFile]":"README2.txt"}},
    {arrayFilters: [{"selectedFile": "README.txt"}]}
)

Comment: by the way, almost forgot, i had to update from 3.2 to 3.6 because this filtering is not supported in 3.2

Answer (score 0):

Well I could update the element in the array doing the following command

```
db.users.update({"directorys.files":"README.txt","email":"doctor@doctor.com"},{"$set":{"directorys.$.files.1":"README2.txt"}})`
```

I have to do some server side work to get that number "1" dynamically but that resolves my question.

I got inspiration from here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114329/mongodb-update-object-in-array